# Find the direct and indirect successors of a node (scala-graph)

Tags: scala, graph, scala-collections

In scala graph the method`diSuccessors` allows to find the direct successors of a node. For example :

```scala
import scalax.collection.mutable.Graph
import scalax.collection.GraphPredef._, scalax.collection.GraphEdge._

val g = Graph(0~>1, 1~>4, 1~>2,2~>3)

g.get(1).diSuccessors //return Set(2, 4): scala.collection.immutable.Set
```

But my problem is to find all the successors that are either directly or indirectly connected to a node. In my example I would have had:

```scala
import scalax.collection.mutable.Graph
import scalax.collection.GraphPredef._, scalax.collection.GraphEdge._

val g = Graph(0~>1, 1~>4, 1~>2,2~>3)

g.get(1).AllSuccessors //return Set(2, 4, 3): scala.collection.immutable.Set
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get `AllSuccessors` by creating a subgraph (`withSubgraphs` method) and removing your node from it.

```
  import scalax.collection.mutable.Graph
  import scalax.collection.GraphPredef._

  val graph = Graph(0 ~> 1, 1 ~> 4, 1 ~> 2, 2 ~> 3)
  val node = graph.get(1)

  val subgraph  = node.withSubgraph().toSet      //Set(1, 2, 4, 3)
  val allSuccessors = subgraph - node            //Set(4, 2, 3)
```